# Good references to study Baker's theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am studying diophantine equations and I need the theory of Bakers, Can you advise me about good books, or lectures on Baker's theory?

Comment: You should probably be more precise about what you mean by "Baker theory", but if you are referring to his theorem on linear combinations of logarithms of algebraic numbers, I can recommend the lecture notes of Soundararajan at http://math.stanford.edu/~ksound/TransNotes.pdf

Comment: @TerryTao I want to study this theory to understand  solving of diophantine equations.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the good place to start is the paper "Linear forms in logarithms" written by Sanda Bujačić and Alan Filipin, which is a part of Diophantine analysis course notes edited by J. Steuding (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-48817-2).

Comment: Many thanks, are there good online courses about this theory, you advise me about?

Comment: I think that the best idea is to learn some generalities and then start to read papers using this methodology. There are so many papers but a good idea is the start with the paper f Baker and Davenport (https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article/20/1/129/1539395).

Comment: Many thanks for your advices.